# Button on navbar causes navbar height to increase

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I refer to the following example on navbar using Bootstrap:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_form&stacked=h

Copying the HTML, I put it in my JSP page. The following is the eventual HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<title>2</title>
</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</nav>
<br>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Navbar Forms</h3>
  <p>Use the .form-inline class to align form elements side by side inside the navbar.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

On both IE and Google Chrome, the navbar's height is bigger than the one in the example, with the extra spaces below the controls, as shown below. I found that this is due to the button. If the button is removed, the navbar's height would be the same as in the example. What could be the root cause and how can I resolve it? I am using Bootstrap 4.4.

[image: What I got]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Can you provide a link or a code snippet (e.g. with jsfiddle)? There must be specific CSS rules causing that problem.

Comment: Can you try this and let me know if that works? in chrome it looks good to me : https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/13920qbp/2/

Comment: Are you using any CSS ?

Comment: recache it first pls: CTRL + SHIFT + DEL

Comment: This is very strange. I found that if I add in <!DOCTYPE html>, the problem would be gone! I tried a few times. If I remove <!DOCTYPE html>, the problem occurs in both IE and Chrome. If I add it, the problem is gone in both browser.

Comment: also as showed in fiddle, make these padding, margin and border to 0 as default that also helps sometimes.

Comment: I used exactly the same codes as in the example. Then I removed <!DOCTYPE html>, and the problem is re-produced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because of the browser default CSS which also known as User Agent Style Sheet.

[image]
I found that if you use `<!DOCTYPE html>` this space was removed because the bottom margin of the form element in HTML5's User agent style sheet is `0px`;

If i don't use `<!DOCTYPE html>` it consider the HTML4's User agent style sheet, and the bottom margin of the form element in it is `1em`.

so now choice is yours that if you have to use `<!DOCTYPE html>` or not.

Otherwise the another solution is that use `class="mb-0"` in form element it is the bootstrap-4 class to set `margin-bottom: 0px;` for any element.

Comment: But I thought <!DOCTYPE html> is just to say the page rendered is HTML. You mean to say that the presence of <!DOCTYPE html> means that it is HTML5?

Comment: yes, exactly <!DOCTYPE html> is rendered the page in HTML5.

Comment: Welcome Dude any time.